# Flask returns 404 in views

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest

I am running unittests in a Flask app and I keep getting 404 when `views.py` file is not imported even though it is not used. I have such `tests.py` package:

```
import unittest

from presence_analyzer import main, utils
from presence_analyzer import views

class PresenceAnalyzerViewsTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = main.app.test_client()

    def test_mainpage(self):
        resp = self.client.get('/')
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 302)
```

When I delete views import the described problem occurs. Views are organized in a similar way to this:

```
from presence_analyzer.main import app

@app.route('/')
def mainpage():

    return redirect('/static/presence_weekday.html')
```

And the `main.py` file:

```
import os.path
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
app.config.update(
    DEBUG=True,
)
```

I guess it's something similar to what happened [in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714995/404-response-when-running-flaskclient-test-method), so I'm trying to change the application so that I don't have to make this dumb imports while testing. I've been trying to make use of the answer from above, but still can't make it work and [these docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/#blueprints) don't seem helpful. What am I doing wrong? `main.py`:

```
from flask.blueprints import Blueprint

PROJECT_NAME = 'presence_analyzer'

blue_print = Blueprint(PROJECT_NAME, __name__)

def create_app():
    app_to_create = Flask(__name__)  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
    app_to_create.register_blueprint(blue_print)
    return app_to_create

app = create_app()
```

`views.py`:

```
from presence_analyzer.main import app, blue_print

@blue_print.route('/')
def mainpage():

    return redirect('/static/presence_weekday.html')
```

And `tests.py` has remained unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must import `views`, or the route will not be registered. No, you are not executing the views directly, but importing executes code all module-level code. Executing code calls `route`. `route` registers the view function. You cannot get around needing to import a module in order to use the module.